# ViewPager inside a Fragment

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment

Is it possible to inflate a `ViewPager` inside a `Fragment` which is inflated on a `Activity`? Coz almost all examples that a found is a `ViewPager` inside a `FragmentActivity` and i dont want to use `FragmentActivity` (for some reason). It will be looked like this photo :

[image]

Please help me, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, but you have to remember the FragmentManager used inside a fragment to manage child Fragment (for example, the one provided to your FragmentPagerAdapter in its constructor) is obtained with [getChildFragmentManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#getChildFragmentManager%28%29) and NOT`getFragmentManager`. That is very important, your app will crash if you don't.

Have a look at [this tutorial](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/actionbarsherlock-side-menu-navigation-nested-viewpager-fragment-tabs-tutorial/) for an example implementation.